# Query SQL Server JSON in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create this query with SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json_field, '$.emails') FROM table
```

Where the field looks like:

```
{"emails": ["email1","email2"...]}
```

I've got something like:

```
session.query(func.json_query(json_field, '$.emails').all()
```

But it looks like `json_query` isn't in func.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read through the [JSON](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.JSON) doc at SQLAlchemy yet?

Comment: I was not able to find it at first, I was searching for mssql not sql server. I found it once someone edited this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it looks like json_query isn't in func

`.func()` does indeed render `json_query`. For a test table named [json_test] …

```
id  json_field
--  -------------------------------  
 1  {"emails": ["email1","email2"]}
 2  {"emails": ["email3","email4"]}
```

… this works for me:

```py
class JsonTest(Base):
    __tablename__ = "json_test"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    json_field = sa.Column(sa.JSON)


with sa.orm.Session(engine) as session:
    qry = session.query(sa.func.json_query(JsonTest.json_field, "$.emails"))
    """SQL emitted:
    2021-08-16 16:24:13,203 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT json_query(json_test.json_field, ?) AS json_query_1 
    FROM json_test
    2021-08-16 16:24:13,203 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00039s] ('$.emails',)
    """
    results = session.execute(qry).fetchall()
    print(results)
    # [('["email1","email2"]',), ('["email3","email4"]',)]
```

Comment: Interesting, I ended up accessing the json by ```query(Table.field['emails'])``` for a similar result.

Comment: Thanks for that. It renders the exact same SQL as noted in the answer. TIL.